# Trouble adding PHP modules to Apache 2.2 Server

Tags: php, apache, module, apache2, httpd.conf

I run a Windows 7 x64 machine with apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2.17

Whenever I try to add the PHP dll to the httpd.conf file, apache will not start.

this is how it is being put into httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

I have successfully managed to setup and run a Apache server with PHP before, so I'm not new to this, but I'm fairly certain that this is right.

Comment: You'll likely get better help over on either ServerFault or SuperUser...

Comment: Is anything being written to the log?

Comment: [Sat Jan 22 22:39:01 2011] [crit] Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.
Pre-configuration failed
[Sat Jan 22 22:39:01 2011] [warn] (OS 995)The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.  : winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.

Comment: You could just go with something like WAMP which installs apache/php/mysql for you in a nice all-in-one package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything that's being output on launch is the DNS error, Apache is launching just fine. FQDN resolution is a warning, not an error.